# db not being selected in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not a programmer or good at programming, just laying this out. I had a site coded for me, but the coder is not interested in further development. I need to rank images in the database by losses (kinda like votes) to views of an image. Originally, here is what was written for the code:

```
// get images 
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `ylyl_images` ORDER BY `loses` DESC LIMIT    $start, 12");
```

That basically orders the images on the site by loses, and to paginate, it has the $start variable which is incremented by 12 for every "next page" click.

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT (`loses`/`views`) AS `ratio` FROM `ylyl_images` WHERE `views` > 150 ORDER BY  `ratio` DESC LIMIT $start, 12");
```

That is what I came up with to order images based on ratio of loses to views, but the query doesn't return anything. I tried replacing the $start variable with just 0, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have records with `views > 150`?

Comment: Do a `SELECT loses,views  FROM ylyl_images order by views DESC` and see how many rows actually have views > 150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you returning the right fields? In the code above, you Changed:

```
SELECT * FROM...
```

To...

```
SELECT loses/views AS ratio FROM...
```

Perhaps you need to return more fields.  While I do not recommend 'SELECT *', you could do the following:

```
SELECT *, loses/views AS ratio FROM...
```

Comment: hmm, thanks, ill try it out, why wouldn't you recommend SELECT? I am a SQL noob, so sorry if thats a dumb question.

Comment: yes! it worked, thank you so much! I should really learn this stuff a lot better, I didn't even know about returning fields, I thought it just returned rows that met the requirements

Comment: I don't recommend selecting all fields using * - it's better to specify all of the fields you need individually.

Comment: oh ok, i only need the image id field, so I can just put in SELECT id, AS etc. right

Comment: Right - just so we're clear, though - SELECT id, loses/views AS ratio... (btw - you seem to be doing alright interpreting the code - better than some, that's for sure!)